# AWS CloudFront behaving different (wrong?) with S3 in EU vs in US

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I followed a really really simple manual to create S3 bucket and put CloudFront in front of it.
See here [1]. If I create the S3 bucket in **us-east-1** everything is working as expected: After I uploaded a file, I can see it via e.g. xyz.cloudfront.net/myExampleFile.txt link.

**But** when I create the S3 bucket in e.g. **eu-west-1** or **eu-central-1**, then as soon as I open the xyz.cloudfront.net/myExampleFile.txt link, my browser gets redirected to the direct S3 bucket link xyz.s3.amazonaws.com/myExampleFile.txt which of course is not working.

--

I have no clue what I could be possibly doing wrong... And due to the fact, that I am not able to submit any support request to AWS directly ("Technical support is unavailable under Basic Support Plan"), I thought I might ask the community here, if anybody else experience the same strange behavior or has any hints, what is going wrong here?

Thank you in advance for any help

Phenix

[1] Step 1,2 and 4 under **Using a REST API endpoint as the origin, with access restricted by an OAI** on https://aws.amazon.com/de/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably encountering the issue described [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-http-307-response/).

> If you're using an Amazon CloudFront distribution with an Amazon S3 origin, **CloudFront forwards requests to the default S3 endpoint (s3.amazonaws.com), which is in the us-east-1 Region**. If you must access Amazon S3 within the first 24 hours of creating the bucket, you can change the Origin Domain Name of the distribution to include the regional endpoint of the bucket. For example, if the bucket is in us-west-2, you can change the Origin Domain Name from bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com to bucketname.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com.

Comment: I do not see that exact response, just a 403 Forbidden, but I will check if my setup in eu-central-1 is ok tomorrow.